# Azure Automation Powershell Scripts - will they function linearly as do SQL Agent Jobs?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I am using Azure Automation to replace my SQL Server Agent Jobs, and I am new to Powershell scripting.  My question is whether creating a script with multiple queries and stored procedure executions will await completion of one task before moving to the next.  In SQL Agent Jobs you can define each step and then instruct it to await success of that step and then`enter code here` move on to the next.

So for example, given this Powershell script:

```
    workflow SyncDataFromTransfer
    {   
        Write-Output "JOB START BEFORE INLINESCRIPT"

        inlinescript
        {
            Write-Output "JOB START"
            # Create connection to Master DB
            $MasterDatabaseConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            $MasterDatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Azure SQL Server;Initial Catalog=SearchDb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user;Password=password;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
            $MasterDatabaseConnection.Open()

            Write-Output "CONNECTION OPEN"

            # Create command
            $MasterDatabaseCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            $MasterDatabaseCommand.Connection = $MasterDatabaseConnection
            $MasterDatabaseCommand.CommandTimeout=0
            $MasterDatabaseCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [SearchDb].IdData
            WHERE TaskId = 1000"

            # Execute the query
            $MasterDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()



            # Close connection to Master DB
            $MasterDatabaseConnection.Close() 

            Write-Output "CONNECTION CLOSED"
        }    
        Write-Output "WORK END - AFTER INLINESCRIPT"

}
```

The question is, if I added a 2nd query directly after the line "`$MasterDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`" will the script wait for the first query to complete successfully before running the 2nd one?

Answer (score 3):

If you want this behaviour, why are you using `workflow`?  One of its primary strengths is doing things in parallel.  Anyway, as per your example, things will execute sequentially.  You can test this by changing the commands to waits and using Profiler, eg

```
$MasterDatabaseCommand.CommandText = "WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01"

# Execute the query
$MasterDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


$MasterDatabaseCommand.CommandText = "WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02"

# Execute the query
$MasterDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If you really want to enforce this behaviour, you should consider using a stored procedure and execute your statements sequentially.

NB Your schema name and database name are the same in your example - typo?

Comment: as to your first question, again I'm new to PS scripting so I'm using workflow as it's what seemed the right solution.  Please do let me know if it makes more sense to use another option.  As to your suggestion for stored procedures, that's certainly doable, but again my question is this.  The first stored procedure I need to run can take up to 4 hours to complete.  Will the script wait that 4 hours for successful completion before executing the next command without me explicitly writing additional code to tell it to wait?

Comment: Yes it will wait; because you are not using any of the `...Async` methods and/or not making multiple calls to your main method `SyncDataFromTransfer`. Try my wait method and see for yourself : )

Comment: I definitely will, and I greatly appreciate the help.  I will test this today and assuming it works as expected, I will mark this as the answer.  Thanks again.